# How can i add readonly attribute on all input fields using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I want to add readonly attribute on all input fields using javascript. I have done for single input field using this `$('#someid').prop('readonly', true);` but I want to add to all input field in Edit Mode.

### Input Fields

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Barcode">Barcode: </label>
    <input name="Barcode" id="Barcode" class="form-control" value="<?=$data['Barcode']?>" placeholder="Barcode">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ApplicantName">ApplicantName: </label>
    <input name="ApplicantName" id="ApplicantName" class="form-control" value="<?=$data['ApplicantName']?>" placeholder="ApplicantName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="SubBarcode">Reference No: </label>
    <input name="SubBarcode" id="SubBarcode" class="form-control" value="<?=$data['SubBarcode']?>" placeholder="Reference No">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ClientName">Client Name: </label>
    <input name="ClientName" id="ClientName" class="form-control" value="<?=$data['ClientName']?>" placeholder="Client Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ClientRefNo">Client Reference No: </label>
    <input name="ClientRefNo" id="ClientRefNo" class="form-control" value="<?=$data['ClientRefNo']?>" placeholder="Client Reference No">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="DateOfBirth">Date Of Birth: </label>
    <input name="DateOfBirth" id="DateOfBirth" class="datetimepicker-month form-control" value="<?=$data['DateOfBirth']?>" placeholder="Date Of Birth">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="PassportNo">Passport No: </label>
    <input name="PassportNo" id="PassportNo" class="datetimepicker-month form-control" value="<?=$data['PassportNo']?>" placeholder="Passport No">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="AKAName">AKAName: </label>
    <input name="AKAName" id="AKAName" class="datetimepicker-month form-control" value="<?=$data['AKAName']?>" placeholder="AKAName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Gender">Gender: </label>
    <input name="Gender" id="Gender" class="datetimepicker-month form-control" value="<?=$data['Gender']?>" placeholder="Gender">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Nationality">Nationality: </label>
    <input name="Nationality" id="Nationality" class="datetimepicker-month form-control" value="<?=$data['Nationality']?>" placeholder="Nationality">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="ArabicName">Arabic Name: </label>
    <input name="ArabicName" id="ArabicName" class="datetimepicker-month form-control" value="<?=$data['ArabicName']?>" placeholder="Arabic Name">
</div>
```

Is there any short way that i can dynamically add read-only attribute to all input fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use element selector with attribute value selector to select all the textboxes and apply the `readonly` property to all of the selected elements.

```
$('input[type="text"]').prop('readonly', true);
```

To select all the textboxes in the form

```
$('yourFormSelector input[type="text"]').prop('readonly', true);
```

As an alternative to attribute value selector, you can also use [`:text`](https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) selector to select all textboxes.

```
$(':text').prop('readonly', true);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `class` for that

```
$('.form-control').prop('readonly', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can specify a common class (recommended) or just globally target all the input elements in the form (not recommended)

```
$('input[type="text"]').prop('readonly', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.classname').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

OR you can use this:

$('.classname').prop('readonly', true);

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        $('input[type="text"]').prop('readonly', true);
    });
</script>
```