# Make all inputs with class readOnly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, formbuilder

So I am building a drag and drop form builder and I want to make a particular field on all the inputs readOnly.
This can be

- Select Dropdown
- Text input
- Number input
- Date input

Date input

[image: example image]

All these inputs will be generated dynamically.

I had a look at 
[How can i add readonly attribute on all input fields using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689874/how-can-i-add-readonly-attribute-on-all-input-fields-using-javascript)
&
[How to set readonly property to false on multiple textboxes with same class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863785/how-to-set-readonly-property-to-false-on-multiple-textboxes-with-same-class)

but none make the name input readOnly just by the class name.

I am currently doing it this way:

```
$("#editClick").on('click', function(){
 $('.myNameClass').attr('readonly', false);
```

});

But need a way to fire it every time a new field appears on the page(i.e. check is the length of a class increases)

Something like:

```
if ($(".myNameClass")[0]).increases -> fire event-> and every time it does
```

Comment: Your question is missing an important part - what you're actually trying to do...? That said, all you need to do to make an input readonly is call `prop('readonly', true)` on it, but make sure you do it *after* the element has been appended to the DOM

Comment: Show us at least some HTML + CSS + possible Javascript which you tried, not just just an image. Also be clear about what it does, vs what you want it do do.

Comment: Your second link shows exactly what your asking for... what don't you understand?

Comment: updated the info there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this using this

jQuery <1.9

```
<script>
    $(function () {
       $('input[type="text"], textarea').attr('readonly','readonly');

    });
</script>
```

or use this for readonly mode

jQuery 1.9+

```
 $(function () {
         $('input[type="text"], textarea').prop("readonly",true);

    });
```

and remove readonly mode

jQuery <1.9

```
     $(function () {
         $('input[type="text"], textarea').removeAttr('readonly');

    });

</script>
```

or use this for remove

jQuery 1.9+

```
 $(function () {
         $('input[type="text"], textarea').prop("readonly",false);

    });
```